# Why does the challenge need to be prime in Wesolowski's succinct argument of $y=x^{e}$?

Tags: snarks, challenge-response, interactive-proofs

In Wesolowski's VDF (verifiable delay function) a prover produces a pair $(x, y)$ and needs to argue to the verifier that the pair satisfies $y = x^e \pmod N$ for some $e$ computable to both. The verifier is compute limited and $e$ is really large, so cannot compute $x^e\pmod N$ herself. The prover needs to convince the verifier with the verifier doing little work.

To achieve this, the verifier generates a challenge $c$ which is prime, and the prover responds with $\pi = x^{\lfloor e/c\rfloor}\pmod N$. Now the verifier can be convinced if $y = \pi^c x^{r}\pmod N$, where $r$ is the remainder of $e$ divided by $c$.

How does the primality of $c$ come into play? Is there a forged proof attack for composite challenges?

In [[1]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/623.pdf) the base difficulty assumption is this game:

**Game 1:** We are given an $N$ guaranteed to be a product of two primes . We choose $u\neq 1$. After this we're given a uniform random k-bit prime $c$. We win if we output $v$ such that $v^c = u\pmod N$.

Does this game become easier if instead we're given just a random k-bit number? The reduction from the VDF problem to Game 1 does not seem to use the fact that $c$ is a prime either.

---

Later on [[2]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/712.pdf) names the statement "Game 1 is hard" the **adaptive root assumption**. They also work with primes only, with no justification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually [[2]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/712.pdf) does have an explanation:

> The reason
> we cannot choose $c$ uniformly in some interval, but must choose it from $\mathrm{Primes}(k)$, is because a
> random $c$ in $\{1, \ldots, 2^k\}$ has a reasonable chance of being a smooth integer.
> The adversary can then win by outputting $u= a^B$ where B is the product of small prime powers up to some bound k,
> and later chosing $v = a^{B/c}$.
> Choosing $c$ as a prime
> number eliminates this attack.

So Game 1 does become easier if we give the player a random $k$ bit integer instead.